# How do I auto-start a Linux app on another window (from panel switcher)?

Tags: linux, window-manager

I want to start a virtual machine on another window panel, but I'm not sure what the command for this would be.

I have:

```
virtualbox --startvm myvin &
```

in my `autostart.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager", and you probably do ([here](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) is a list), then you can use `wmctrl` to move the program to another desktop/workspace after it is already started. VirtualBox appears to put the VM name in the Window title, so something like this will probably work for you:

```
virtualbox --startvm myvin &
sleep 2 # adjust accordingly
wmctrl -r myvin -t 1 # move window containing title 'myvin' to the 2nd desktop
```

`wmctrl` may not be installed by default. Install it using your distribution's package-manager if necessary (i.e. `apt-get install wmctrl` on debian based systems).

Helpful for troubleshooting:

`wmctrl -d` lists the available desktops.

`wmctrl -l` lists the available windows (includes window title value).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm using openbox. I will give this a try.